# How to get tx level during call by using AT-Command

Tags: gsm, at-command, modem

I want to know the `tx level` of my mobile. I have an `AT` command terminal, and I just want the `AT` command that make me get the `tx level`.

I tried this command:

```
AT*PSENGI=2
```

but the modem returns:

```
Error
```

also this command returns `Error`

```
AT+CMGI
```

but

```
AT+CGMR
```

returns:

```
8x25Q-QSOSKLYM-3030 1 [jan 29 2013 07:00:00]
OK
```

Comment: What kind of modem/mobile do you have? What does `AT+CMGI` and `AT+CGMR` return? AT*PSENGI is not a standard command so it must be a proprietary command from some manufacturer.

Comment: I use Samsung Galaxy Win Duos. but I want my program to run on HTC mobiles too.about the response of those two command I will Edit the Q.

Comment: @hlovdal could you give me a file that contain at commands suit my modem. I find it a bit difficult to get the right command.

Comment: AT*PSENGI is an engineering command for some Sierra Wireless modems as I recall. This command is not an official part of the modem delivery.

Comment: Please add your modem manufacturer and model. We can help a lot more then. Also by tx level you mean the signal quality?

Comment: On a side note to list available AT commands for your modem you can execute AT+CLAC

Comment: @aldridmc, thank u very much for your response. I don't know my modem manufacturer. how can I get it? I google it (Samsung galaxy win duos modem) but I don't find any thing help me.

Comment: ATI should do the trick

Comment: @aldridmc AT+CLAC didn't work at all. where ATI got me Manufacturer, Model, revision, IMEI, and +GCAP. which one would help me to find the suitable command for my modem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54108/discussion-between-aldridmc-and-miracle-mo).

Answer (score 0):

As this is a built in modem on a mobile phone there is no documentation available.

Generally such information as TX level is usually obtained via diagnostics interfaces such as QXDM rather than AT Commands. There are some manufacturers that do provide a little more information in the form of manufacturer specific AT commands but this is rare.

Comment: What is the answer if we use external modem?

Comment: Depends on the modem manufacturer and model. When there is a proper AT command interface you have a higher chance of getting manufacturer specific diagnostics information.

Comment: Could u provide me some types that help me to read low level info. like rx, tx level, rx qual, l3 messages, BISC, ARFCN and so. This Question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694918/what-are-the-information-that-can-gsm-modem-get

Comment: Well I know that the Cinterion (Siemens) MC55i and Sierra Wireless MC8795V have some special commands that can get this information through custom AT commands. Both are embedded modems (but for example the Sierra Wireless I have in a USB to mPCIe convertor connected to a Raspberry PI).

Comment: now I'm using an external modem (I think It's easier to deal with). Could u provide me also types of external modem and advice me to choose a suitable interface to get low level info. Thanks a lot :)