# What are the information that can GSM modem get?

Tags: gsm, modem

I want to know about `GSM modems`. I need low level info.

Can the modem get me Layer 3 Messages, `Rx` and `Tx` level, `Rx Qual.`, `C/I`, `BCCH`, `BISC`, `ARFCN` and ...

**Edit**

Note: I'm not asking about embedded modems only, I'm asking on both embedded and external modems.

Thanks and Best Regards

Comment: What interface are you using to get information from the modem?  If AT commands, what's the manufacturer?

Comment: Actually I'm beginner in using modems so I want to know if modem can help in my project or not. Could u help choose an interface that help me to get the above info. and Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet for low level information is AT commands.  See the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585159/android-how-to-read-low-level-network-info-rscp-ecn0-layer-3-signalling/14622810#14622810) for specific commands for the information that you want.

Although it's about Android, you can assess AT commands on any operating system, as long as the modem device exposes a modem port (It may sound obvious that any modem would expose a modem port, but this is not the case.  Some modems appear in Windows as network adapters, for example).

But note that Layer 3 messages aren't available over the AT interface.  You would need a diagnostic tool from the chipset manufacturer to read the air interface messages.  These are not usually available unless you're a partner company or customer of the manufacturer.

Edit:
Embedded and external modems are treated the same.  The best interface to use depends on the driver.  AT commands work with the vast majority of modems.  Read the [AT command manual](http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/27007.htm) for information that you can get via AT commands.
Try to get hold of a manual of manufacturer specific commands that are particular to your chosen modem.
Use AT+CLAC to get all the supported AT commands of your particular modem.

L3 messages arrive via the air interface.  As I said before, the chipset manufacturers have their own interfaces to access this information, but these are not public.

Comment: I made an edit, please have a look. Is there another interface that gets L3 messages? Can AT-Commands get all parameters except L3 messages on android mobile (embedded modems)? Thanx